# Using a loop to pack widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pack

I'm still new to tkinter (and python I suppose). I have a program with quite a few Label widgets, and rather than packing every widget individually I'd like to be able to pack them all in one go.
My original strategy was using a for loop and a list, like so:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

l1 = Label(root, text="hello")
l2 = Label(root, text="world")

varList = ['l1', 'l2']
for r in range(1,2):
    varList[r].pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I realise now that this won't work since I'm packing strings and not variables, but am not sure how to do it alternatively (dictionaries?).

Also, in my original code I establish all the values individually, since, they all hold different text and sticky values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the actual widgets rather than the name of the widgets:

```
varList = [l1, l2]
for label in varList:
    label.pack()
```